# NoSQL database for highly structured, many-index, mission-critical data with lots of relationships

Tags: database, sql, nosql

I'm trying to find an alternative to SQL which is very horizontally scalable. However, many NoSQL databases have some features I need missing from SQL, or some other weird quirks.

I am developing an app with some data with lots of relationships (which requires joins and foreign keys), some entities which contain financial amounts (so requires atomicity of transactions). Some of the entities in the data model also have many (five or more) separate indexes which can all be used for filtering under different scenarios. This makes NoSQL databases difficult to use. However, I hope to store many GBs of data, and want to be able to scale up if necessary.

I'm wondering if there is a NoSQL database that can be used for very SQL-like purposes?

Comment: I hear that NoSQL databases excel at distributed-computing workloads with dozens of nodes. If you need concurrency control, indexing, full-text-indexing, transactions and data-modeling tools, on a single node (or very few), relational databases are much simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to post a comment so I'm asking here: why not use a relational SQL database? They are scalable, there are many to choose from whatever your budget or tech stack.

If there is a specific reason you're looking for a no-SQL solution, please add it to your question.

Comment: I've heard that SQL databases are not very scalable.